# Alternating Ordination

Tags: java

Given a sequence of numbers in the array, return these numbers arranged alternately, that is, the lowest numbers, followed by the most, followed by the second lowest, followed by the second highest, and so on.

Input: 1 2 3 4 5
output: 1 5 2 4 3

input: 10 5 7 9 2 2
output: 2 10 2 9 5 7

I try something like this, but not working for me, can help me please.
I need two output into the same function or method.

public class Test{
    int[] inputArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

```
void mergeSort(int[] array) {
    int[] helper = new int[array.length];
    mergesort(array, helper, 0, array.length - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}

private void mergesort(int[] array, int[] helper, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        mergesort(array, helper, low, middle);
        mergesort(array, helper, middle + 1, high);
        merge(array, helper, low, middle, high);

    }

}

private void merge(int[] array, int[] helper, int low, int middle, int high) {
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        helper[i] = array[i];
    }
    int helperLeft = low;
    int counter = 0;
    int helperRight = middle + 1;
    int current = low;
    while (helperLeft <= middle && helperRight <= high) {
        if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            if (helper[helperLeft] <= helper[helperRight]) {
                array[current] = helper[helperLeft];
                helperLeft++;
            } else {
                array[current] = helper[helperRight];
                helperRight++;
            }

        } else {
            if (helper[helperLeft] >= helper[helperRight]) {
                array[current] = helper[helperLeft];
                helperLeft++;
            } else {
                array[current] = helper[helperRight];
                helperRight++;
            }

        }
        counter++;
        current++;
    }
    int remaining = middle - helperLeft;
    for (int i = 0; i <= remaining; i++) {
        array[current + i] = helper[helperLeft + i];
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Solution i = new Solution();
    i.mergeSort(i.inputArray);

}
```

}

output : 1,4,3,5,2

Comment: How about just sorting the array, and then picking the element 0, then the element n-1, then the element 1, then the element n-2, until you reach the middle of the array? Java has Arrays.sort() already, so it shouldn't be more than very few lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first start off by sorting the array as normal, then use it to alternate in the way you want.

```
int[] toReturn = new int[inputArray.length];

Arrays.sort(inputArray);

for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i+=2) {
    toReturn[i] = inputArray[i/2];
}
for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i+=2) {
    toReturn[i] = inputArray[inputArray.length - i/2 - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sort your array then perform this operation:

- initialize two variables : `i = 0` and `j = array.length - 1`
- while `j > i` then print `array[i]` followed by `array[j]`
- increase `i` and decrease `j`
- at the end of the loop, print `array[i]` (to handle the case when `i == j`)

Here is a sample code:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
int i = 0, j = array.length - 1;
while (i < j) {
    System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    System.out.print(array[j] + " ");
    i++;
    j--;
}
if (i == j) {
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: I found the answer to first array output : 1,5,2,4,3                                     But the second array i found a error when i run code.                                      i need to output : 2 10 2 9 5 7